# Powershell select values between

Tags: powershell

I have a script that provides the sunrise and sunset times yesterday ($sunrise and $sunset, formatted as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss).  I have a file (could be txt or csv) where the first column has a timestamp in the format of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss and the second column has a number in the format of XX.X.  Using Powershell Get-Content, I am trying to return all of the values that are between the sunrise and sunset times, inclusive.  Using Select, I can get singular values, but I can't figure out how to get multiple, let alone a range.

```
Get-Content C:\uv.txt | select (between $sunrise & $sunset)
```

Input (uv.txt):

```
2020-08-11 06:00:00 0.0
2020-08-11 07:00:00 0.0
2020-08-11 08:00:00 0.6
2020-08-11 09:00:00 1.4
2020-08-11 10:00:00 4.2
2020-08-11 11:00:00 6.2
2020-08-11 12:00:00 8.4
2020-08-11 13:00:00 9.3
2020-08-11 14:00:00 9.2
2020-08-11 15:00:00 7.6
2020-08-11 16:00:00 5.6
2020-08-11 17:00:00 3.3
2020-08-11 18:00:00 1.6
2020-08-11 19:00:00 0.5
2020-08-11 20:00:00 0.0
2020-08-11 21:00:00 0.0
2020-08-11 22:00:00 0.0
```

Simplified script that is not working (no output in console or if I send to out-file):

```
$sunrise  = "2020-08-12 06:32:17"
$sunset   = "2020-08-12 20:06:33"

Get-Content C:\daily_values_uv.txt | Where-Object { $_ -ge $sunrise -and $_ -le $sunset }
```

Comment: Understood, @mklement0.  Maybe I'll look at a different way of doing this.  I create the input file via a mysql query, which I can via batch or powershell.  And I've been trying to figure out the easiest way to manipulate the results....doing so within the mysql query or doing so in batch or ps.

Comment: Given the choice between batch and PowerShell, PowerShell is definitely the way to go: it has vastly superior capabilities. For instance, you could cast your timestamp strings to `[datetime]` to get `System.DateTime` instances (e.g., `[datetime] '2020-08-10 00:00:00'`) that you can also compare with `-ge` and `-le` and also perform time-span calculations on.

Comment: If this is in a database, wouldn't it be more efficient to query the database directly rather than extract more data than needed and then script it after the fact?

Comment: Bill, definitely.  However, I couldn't figure out how to tie it all together.  I wasn't able to determine how to create the variables in mysql (for sunrise/sunset) so I created them in PS.  Then, I couldn't determine how to pass them into mysql (accessed via phpmyadmin or batch or ps) so I decided to see if I could take the output from mysql and then manipulate it.  Complicated, right

Comment: @mklement0 I agree, PS is the way to go.  What else can I provide you that may assist you in ultimately assisting me?  I tested the script Mathias provided which appears to work (it doesn't error) but the output is just empty.  The only different in my example above is that the input file has values for every minute of the day, both timestamp and uv value.

Comment: Okay @mklement0 should now be MCVE.  I updated the txt file to only include values on the hour from 6am - 10pm.  I set $sunrise and $sunset equal to their actual values (instead of including the script used to calculate them).  I reran this simplified version on the simplified input and still have the same results with blank output.  If I remove the `where-object` statement, `get-content` returns the entire txt file.

Comment: Your input lines all fall into calendar day `2020-08-11`, whereas your comparison variables fall into `2020-08-12` - you shouldn't expect any output.

Comment: Oh my...... @mklement0 you're right!  And I found the issue.  A single missing letter caused the api to pull today instead of yesterday.....I should have caught this a day ago.  Now on to adjusting the resulting txt file to remove the timestamps.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the big endian date format, you can do:

```
Get-Content C:\uv.txt | Where-Object { $_ -gt $sunrise -and $_ -lt $sunset }
```